# While loop not working as expected with variable

Tags: php, while-loop

The following code works fine when i remove the `&& $f<4`, but with it in, it doesn't work.

PHP:

```
$titles=array();
$f=0;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query) && $f<4){  //this line doesn't work
        $titles[]=$row['questiontitle'];
            echo "<div class='questionPreview'>$titles[$f]</div>";
            $f++;
        }
```

Comment: @deceze when the inequality is removed the div works but there are no titles.  When i remove the inequality, i get the div and titles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I interpret you correctly I think you are having a precedence problem.  Try this:

```
while (($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) && ($f<4)){
```

Comment: a better way is to change the order of the expressions and let $f<4 be first. It won't do a useless fetch when $f >= 4.

Answer (score 2):

[=`has lower precedence than`&&](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). This means that the `&&` operator is evaluated first.

This means that your code, in effect, looks like this:

```
while ($row = (mysql_fetch_assoc($query) && $f<4)){  //this line doesn't work
```

So, in other words, do the MySQL query and the comparison, and if they are both true, set `$row` to `true`; otherwise, set it to `false`.

You need to use brackets to ensure that the right operations are done:

```
while (($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) && ($f<4)){
```

Comment: Or just using `AND` instead of `&&`.

Answer (score 1):

That is probably because `$row` is `true` rather then the array:

```
$ php -r 'var_dump($row = pow(2,2) && true,$row);'
bool(true)
bool(true)
$ php -r 'var_dump($row = pow(2,2) && false,$row);'
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

(`pow` being a random function here)

That is because `&&` has a higher [precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) then `=`. As always, solve with `()`:

```
while ( ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ) && $f<4){
```